# How to solve Python praw error : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Here is code -   I try google but did not find solution :(

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                        
import praw                                                                                                   
import sys                                                                                                    


AUTOREPLY_MSG = """\                                                                                          
Hey there, I'm on a vacation for x days.                                                                      

I won't check this account till then. Happy Holidays! """                                                     


def main():                                                                                                   
    r = praw.Reddit('bot1', user_agent='bot1 user agent')                                                     

    for msg in r.inbox.unread(mark_read=True):                                                                
        if isinstance(msg, praw.objects.Message):                                                             
            msg.reply(AUTOREPLY_MSG)                                                                          
            msg.mark_as_read()                                                                                
            print(msg, file=sys.stderr)                                                                       


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                    
    main()                                                                                                    
~
```

Comment: Go and read the docs properly https://pypi.python.org/pypi/praw you're calling `.objects` on a module that doesn't have that property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `praw.objects` submodule. What you want is `praw.models` and you should *probably* import that explicitly at the top. The following might work for you. Cheers!

```
import praw
import praw.models
import sys
AUTOREPLY_MSG = """\                                                                                          
Hey there, I'm on a vacation for x days.                                                                      

I won't check this account till then. Happy Holidays! """                                                     


def main():                                                                                                   
    r = praw.Reddit('bot1', user_agent='bot1 user agent')                                                     

    for msg in r.inbox.unread(mark_read=True):                                                                
        if isinstance(msg, praw.models.Message):                                                             
            msg.reply(AUTOREPLY_MSG)                                                                          
            msg.mark_as_read()                                                                                
            print(msg, file=sys.stderr)                                                                       


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                    
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Probably a silly question, new to python, got an error  AUTOREPLY_MSG: command not found
Am I messing up some syntax?